# How to abstract React state logic to custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component like this:

```
export const MyComp = () => {
    const [showRules, setShowRules] = useState(false)

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowRules(!showRules)} activeOpacity={1}>
                <View>
                    <Inner expand={showRules}>
                        <Text>Content here </Text>
                    </Inner>
                </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

I have another component where I expand/collapse stuff just like this. the logic is duplicated, just the state has different names. thought it could be a good use case for a custom hook

so I wrote this

```
    export const useExpander = (setExpand) => {
        const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
        useEffect(() => {
            if (setExpand) {
                setShow(true)
            } else {
                setShow(false)
            }
        }, [])
    
        return show
    }
```

but I can't figure out how to use it?

I cant change this line: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => useExpander(expand)} activeOpacity={1}>`

as I think this violates hook rules

any ideas?

Comment: In this case I don't see useful to use a custom hook to set property to true or false

Comment: it seems like repeated logic though across components. historically I could wrap this in a HOC but I don't like using HOCs now we have hooks